# Excel Solver LP with Count constraint

Tags: excel, solver

I am doing a linear program with Excel Solver to minimize costs across different suppliers, and I was wondering if I could add a constraint that limits the total number of suppliers used? When I try the Count function, it counts everything unless the cell is blank, but solver puts in a zero if the supplier gets no volume. And Countif makes it nonlinear. Is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

```
objective - min P1V1 + P2V2 + P3V3 ...
        s.t count (V1, V2, V3 etc) <= 3
      where Pn= price of supplier n
            Vn = volume of supplier n
```

In this case, multiple suppliers provide volume for a single item, and I am trying to limit the total suppliers to 3.

Edit: Also, the volume is going to several different plant locations. Is there also a way to limit the number of suppliers per plant?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`? If you use a sum of the Binary used in the solver it should work

Comment: i did not use a binary variable in this problem. Is there a way to do this without creating a binary variable?

Comment: If you  want to keep it linear you need to add binary variables.

Comment: i would need a binary variable for each plant/supplier combo right? so if i had 5 suppliers and 5 plants, then i need 25 binary variables?

Comment: If you want to count suppliers you one need 5. If you want to count supplier-plants links then 25.